# Animate list items from left one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

How can I animate list items to slide from the left and fade in one by one? With animation starting 1 s after the button is clicked?

HTML:

```
<button>Click</button>

<ul>  
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {list-style-type: none; display:none;}
```

JS:

```
$("button").click(function(){

  $("ul").fadeIn();

});
```

CodePen:

http://codepen.io/i76/pen/YGkaZv

Answer (score 6):

You can use `translateX()` to make slideIn effect and `opacity` for fadeIn and add that with class. You can also use `delay()` to make animations on elements run one after another.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("li").delay(500).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(100 * i).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("show");
    })
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, works in Firefox but not Safari. Adding -webkit- prefix did not help...

Comment: It works for me on 2023 :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't include a fade in (you could animate opacity by yourself), but you could use a staggered list of [materialize-css](http://materializecss.com/transitions.html#!)

**Edit:** although the demo shows the use of a button click, you can do it anyway you like by calling

```
Materialize.showStaggeredList('#staggered-test')
```

Where you should replace `#staggered-test` with a selector matching your list.

Comment: Thanks but I am already using Foundation and eventually I'd like the animation to start when menu slides in, so no button click.

Comment: The demo on the site works on a button click, but you can do it any way you like (even from inside an interval or another event)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Greensocks](http://greensock.com/) [`TweenMax.staggerTo`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/staggerTo/) ,[`TweenMax.staggerFrom`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/staggerFrom/) and [`TweenMax.staggerFromTo`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/staggerFromTo/) will do the job.

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with pure CSS sadly (I wish!) so here is a solution using JQuery and recursion.

Apparently Stackoverflow's snippet tool doesn't allow for jquery so here is the code without the tool.

JavaScript

```
function fadeInSequentially (element) {
  if (element == null || element.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  $(element).fadeIn(400, function () {
    fadeInSequentially($(element).next());
  });
}

$("button").click(function(){

  setTimeout(function() {
  fadeInSequentially($("li").first());

   }, 800);

});
```

CSS

```
ul {list-style-type: none;}
li {display:none;}
```

HTML

```
<ul>  
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'display: none;' to li and then use setTimeout() to have 1s gaps between appearing of each li.
Here is your corrected code:

```
ul {list-style-type: none; }

li {display:none;}
```

```
$("button").on('click', function(){
  var i = 0;
  $('ul li').each(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.fadeIn();
    }, i*1000);
    i++;
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/WGpJvw?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom CSS.

**CSS**

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    ul > li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px 6px;
    color: #34495e;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
 ul > li:before {
    content: "\f105";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 31px;
    right: 10px;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
    top: 7px;
    color: #6f6f6f;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Click</button>

<ul>  
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $("button").on('click', function(){
    $('ul> li').each(function (i) {
           $(this).delay(300 * i).animate({ opacity: 1, left: 0 }, 800);
      });
    });

</script>
```

Fiddler link https://jsfiddle.net/2jro7kco/